# How to get values of a date range even if a particular date is not having data in table, using impala-shell

Tags: hive, impala

I would like to get the data for a date range, in this date range, some of the dates are not having any date in the table. Query results are not showing anything for those dates as shown below, there is no data for the dates starting from 2023-07-14.

### query

`select count(*),to_date(date_column) as cdate  from table where  to_date(date_column) > '2023-07-11' group by 2 order by 2;`

```
+----------+----------------------------+
| count(*) | cdate                      |
+----------+----------------------------+
| 413      | 2023-07-12                 |
| 316      | 2023-07-13                 |
| 400      | 2023-08-11                 |
| 302      | 2023-08-12                 |
| 325      | 2023-08-13                 |
| 13       | 2023-08-14                 |
| 767      | 2023-08-15                 |
+----------+----------------------------+
```

I would like to get the result in below expected format.

```
+----------+----------------------------+
| count(*) | cdate                      |
+----------+----------------------------+
| 413      | 2023-07-12                 |
| 316      | 2023-07-13                 |
| 0        | 2023-07-14                 |
| 0        | 2023-07-15                 |
| 0        | 2023-07-16                 |
| 0        | 2023-07-17                 |
| 0        | 2023-07-18                 |
+----------+----------------------------+
```

**If there is no data for a date, return 0 as the count value.**

Answer (score 0):

Pls use `sum()` for that condition -

```
select 
sum(case when to_date(date_column) > '2023-07-11' then 1 else 0 end ) as cnt,
to_date(date_column) as cdate  
from table where  group by 2 
order by 2;
```